# validate Bootstrap form in Cakephp

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

When i use Form Helper of Cakephp, it can be validated in Model with many rules like this: (for example)

```
$this->validate = array(
      "name" => array(
           "rule" => "notBlank",
           "message" => "Name not empty !",
       ),
       "email" => array(
           "rule" => "notBlank", 
           "message" => "Email not empty !", 
        ),

    );
```

Bootstrap Form:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

. But when i use Form created in Bootstrap, the validation is not occured.

How to fix that????

Comment: Please show your view code as well. Also, where do you want to show the error messages? Right below the input boxes?

Comment: can you please show more code you have tried

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use Form helper  then your input field name should be  `name="data[Modelname][fieldname]"` 
Base on it your code should be (if your model is `Users`)

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="data[User][name]" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="data[User][email]" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Details is [Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)